# jsch JSchAlgoNegoFailException Algorithm negotiation fail

Tags: jsch

Using jsch-0.2.17.jar

I can connect using WINSCP but not jsch

I am setting these properties:
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
config.put("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", "ssh-rsa");

Getting this error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchAlgoNegoFailException: Algorithm negotiation fail: algorithmName="server_host_key" jschProposal="ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256" serverProposal="ssh-rsa"
```

Setting this configuration

Logs:

```
INFO: Connecting to HOSTNAME port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-_ SFTP
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH_0.2.17
INFO: CheckCiphers: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
INFO: CheckKexes: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve448-sha512
INFO: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com is not available.
INFO: curve25519-sha256 is not available.
INFO: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org is not available.
INFO: curve448-sha512 is not available.
DEBUG: kex proposal before removing unavailable algos is: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
DEBUG: kex proposal after removing unavailable algos is: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
INFO: CheckSignatures: ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed448
INFO: ssh-ed25519 is not available.
INFO: ssh-ed448 is not available.
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal before removing unavailable algos is: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal after removing unavailable algos is: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal before known_host reordering is: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
DEBUG: server_host_key proposal after known_host reordering is: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: server proposal: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO: server proposal: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
INFO: server proposal: ciphers c2s: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
INFO: server proposal: ciphers s2c: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
INFO: server proposal: MACs c2s: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256
INFO: server proposal: MACs s2c: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256
INFO: server proposal: compression c2s: zlib,none
INFO: server proposal: compression s2c: zlib,none
INFO: server proposal: languages c2s: 
INFO: server proposal: languages s2c: 
INFO: client proposal: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
INFO: client proposal: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
INFO: client proposal: ciphers c2s: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
INFO: client proposal: ciphers s2c: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
INFO: client proposal: MACs c2s: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: client proposal: MACs s2c: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: client proposal: compression c2s: none
INFO: client proposal: compression s2c: none
INFO: client proposal: languages c2s: 
INFO: client proposal: languages s2c: 
INFO: Disconnecting from HOSTNAME port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchAlgoNegoFailException: Algorithm negotiation fail: algorithmName="server_host_key" jschProposal="ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256" serverProposal="ssh-rsa"
```

Appreciate any help?

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure jsch to accept insecure server config like described in the FAQ on https://github.com/mwiede/jsch?tab=readme-ov-file#why-do-ssh-rsa-type-keys-not-work-with-this-jsch-fork-and-my-server

For example

```
JSch.setConfig("server_host_key", JSch.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-rsa");
JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", JSch.getConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms") + ",ssh-rsa")
```